# React Native Application has not been registered

Tags: react-native, tracking

when i have create app first time by (react-native init AwesomeProject) this command. its create successfully.
I want to run in iOS. run (cd Route) and (react-native run-ios).

I'm getting this error:

[image: This is simulator screen]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React-Native: Application has not been registered error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340360/react-native-application-has-not-been-registered-error)

Comment: I've checked this already. But don't know what's the error.

Comment: I also got same error in android emulator. But i didnot get any solution for this problem.