# Application main has not been registered

Tags: react-native, expo

I have recently started to convert my react native app and running on Expo so i could test this on my actual android device. I am getting this error above. I have since then running my app using the Expo XDE. I am also running on a windows machine.

The full error message is:

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbxKr.png)

I figured that this has something to do with my index.js, yet here it is

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('projectTARA', () => 'App');
```

Comment: What version of expo are you using?

Comment: Did you change the name of the project ?

Comment: im using expo "25.0.0.0" . @QoP,

Comment: and no i did change the name of my project. my root folder is called projectTARA @Rafael Motta

Comment: solved the issue i had to change AppRegistry.registerComponent('main', =>  App);

Comment: wow changing the registerComponent to 'main' instead of the name of my project 'AwesomeProject' worked, but I've not seen this documented anywhere, quite the opposite, I see everyone else say to use the name of your app here.  Thank You @johnobc!!!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The following solution worked:

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('main',() => App);
```

Credits: Rishav Kumar

*(Cannot you people just reply to mark as solve ?)*

Comment: Well though this may help, the reason depends on how is "index.android" or "index.ios" in native code. For example in android case last answer here could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340360/react-native-application-has-not-been-registered-error/57336321#57336321

Comment: Is this supposed to be typed at the command prompt or placed in a file?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you haven't opened your project in  Android Studio. The previous project is running in android studio and you are running the latest one in emulator.

Comment: **AppRegistry.registerComponent('main',() => App);**
This is how the error was solved

Comment: @RishavKumar without any import from app.json ?

Comment: @Gha app.json? What does it has to do ?

Comment: Try this one : import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App'; AppRegistry.registerComponent('main',() => App);

Answer (score 2):

I created a Project from "Doco", and save it with Practice. so write that line like that

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('Practice', () => FixedDimensionsBasics);
```

then I get an error like in a question

So, I check on my Appdelegate.m file on ios folder and find that Project name is Project
so I change that line with

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('Project', () => FixedDimensionsBasics);
```

and my Error solved

so if you are using "Doco" then check that thing.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue because I had previously run a React project that was not fully shut down. To fix this, I could have restarted my computer. But I chose to do this instead: (Using MacOS, should work with Linux as well, for Windows you would likely need to use Task Manager or similar):

1. Open terminal
2. Find the program that is using port 8081 by typing "lsof -i :8081". (Note this is LSOF in lowercase)
3. Look at the process ID (under the PID column)
4. Kill the process by typing "kill -9 *PID*" (where *PID* is the process ID number you found in step 3).

After killing the process you should be able to run your react-native project.

Answer (score 1):

Removed node_modules and reinstalled by yarn that worked for me.

Comment: this happened to me because I globally updated expo but the project was generated with an older version, so your solution did the trick

Answer (score 0):

**Error ?**  if you are running your app on the expo framework, the framework cannot find registration of the main App,or its entry point.

**Solution ?**  go to you entry script, could be "src/main.js" or in my case the "App.js"
then;

```
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';

export default function App(){
    //your code app code goes here
}

registerRootComponent(App);
```

Refer here: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/register-root-component/