# Expo does not find "main" application in production build?

Tags: react-native, build, expo

I've been trying to fix this error from a couple weeks ago with no success. The problem is I cannot publish my app because of this.

When I build my expo app for any of both, iOS or Android, the Expo CLI signing process goes well, no errors and generates final bundles but when I install the spa or apk file into a real device it shows the splash screen 4 or 5 times in a row (some kind of loop) and finally shows the following error messages:

[image]

Checked out with no results:

https://forums.expo.io/t/application-main-has-not-been-registered/14395

[Application main has not been registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49410115/application-main-has-not-been-registered)

https://forums.expo.io/t/application-main-has-not-been-registered/11753

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "Sxunco",
  "homepage": "https://www.sxunco.com",
  "version": "1.0.3",
  "private": true,
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!((jest-)?react-native|react-clone-referenced-element|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|react-navigation|redux-persist|native-base(-shoutem-theme)|native-base|react-native-router-flux))"
    ]
  },....
```

My App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import Root from './src/native/index';
import configureStore from './src/store/index';

const { persistor, store } = configureStore();

export default function App() {
  return <Root store={store} persistor={persistor} />;
}
```

Ive tried with same results:

- Adding `"appKey": "main"` into app.json
- Adding `AppRegistry.registerComponent(‘main’, () => App);` into App.js and also expo `registerRootComponent(App)` (separated and both together, none of that works)
- Changing "main" path in
  package.json directly to App.js and register app with above methods
  manually

When I run build I also run:

```
exp start --no-dev --minify
```

So I wait for the server to finish loading and then run `expo build:android`

Please I don't know what to do, I cannot publish my app because of this.

Comment: Hi @karlo I have the same issue, how did you solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

**1) check index.js and make sure yourAppName is registered, not `main`:**

`app.json` file from root folder:

```
{
  "name": "TestSvgJoy",
  "displayName": "TestSvgJoy"
}
```

`index.js` (from root folder, if you don't have it there you need to update build scripts in Xcode as below)

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

This is how app would look in Xcode:

[image]

**2) 
 AppDelegate.m should have 2 lines like this**

```
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
```

Note: if you are using Expo and app was not detached you can ignore this step.

**3) Make sure your root folder contains the index.js or index.ios.js.**

Note: 
If you need custom path of `entryFile` (`index.js` or `index.ios.js`) go to `Xcode, project target, Build Phases, Bundle ReactNative code and images`and provide an extra parameter like `./src/index.ios.js`

[image]
To test things quickly and get more info about the errors go to `Xcode, Product, Scheme, Edit Scheme, Run, Build Configuration` and set it to `Release` and run it on the simulator.

[image]

Comment: Hi Florin, thanks for answer. I've tried to put `"main":"App.js"` property over package.json and put `AppRegistry.registerComponent("Sxunco", () => App());` in App.js end but nothing, same result

Comment: Hi, Karlo, I updated my answer with more details. Double check step 1 and make sure index.js (or index.ios.js) is present in the root folder. (step 3)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my App is a function, and I was just passing the function itself to both registration methods (react native & expo):

`registerRootComponent(App())`

`AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App());`

But in `registerRootComponent` I was missing an arrow function :S

`registerRootComponent(()=>App())`

:)

Comment: I think you don't have to use AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App()); as expo itself manage that by registerRootComponent.

Comment: I think you don't have to use AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App()); as expo itself manage that by registerRootComponent.